# Access Chrome Mobile Browser History SDK >= 23 Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, browser-history, bookmarks, keylogger, mobile-chrome

I'm trying to access the browser history of the user and display it from my app. From what I've read, Android used to support using Browser.BOOKMARKS to do this, but it got removed in Android 23 and up. I've looked through Chrome's API and other StackOverflow posts but I can't find a way to access the history. Is there any possible way to do this on SDK >= 23? Does Chrome perhaps provide a way to access this information in Android? Even indirect methods like logging keypresses in Chrome, or somehow accessing the text displayed on the user's screen is fine.